# Rename Realm DB file name in Android

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I have a Realm DB file, with name "abc.realm". How to change this name to something else? Should I just replace the file name using IO operations or can I do it with migrations? Not able to find any satisfactory answer neither on the web nor on StackOverflow.

Comment: A file is a file and can be renamed if you have write access to the file location. It is unclear which problem you actually have.

Comment: The question is unclear - are you saying you don't know how to rename a file in general? Or are you asking how to rename a file via code? Migrations are designed to handle situations where you're making destructive changes to your models - is that the case? Can you update your question with the code you've attempted so we can see where your stuck? Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm stores 2 files, the realm itself and a .lock file. So if you call your realm *"abc.realm"*, then next to this file there is also *"abc.realm.lock"*.

The way to go about renaming your realm file is,

1. Make sure you find the location of both files
2. Rename both files with the same name but keeping the ".lock" extension on the lock file
3. Modify the path to the realm that you pass to the `RealmConfigurationBase` inheritor

Clearly before doing any of this, make sure to backup your database, just in case.

I don't know what programming language you're writing your android application in, so I'll go with a skeleton in pseudocode

```cs
private void BackupRealmFile(string realmLocation, string saveLocation)
{
    // make a copy of the file and store it somewhere
}

void YourMainMethod()
{
    BackupRealmFile("some/path", "your/backup/path");

    IOLib.RenameFile("some/path/abc.realm", "some/path/newName.realm");
    IOLib.RenameFile("some/path/abc.realm.lock", "some/path/newName.realm.lock");

    var config = new RealmConfiguration("some/path/newName.realm");
    // maybe some more settings on your conf

    var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, comprehensive answer and +1 for stating to backup the database. One point to note is this answer only applies to a *local only* realm. A synced Realm is a totally different beast.

Comment: Thank you Jay. Concerning the synced Realm, the local realm file holding synced data can be renamed in the same way mentioned above. What are you referring to?

Comment: @Jay that is completely incorrect. The filename of a realm is completely unrelated from its content. And this is true for both local and synced realm (be it partition based or flexible). This is also why e.g. in .NET you can have optional path in RealmConfigaration's inheritors [[1]](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/dotnet/latest/reference/Realms.Sync.FlexibleSyncConfiguration.html#Realms_Sync_FlexibleSyncConfiguration__ctor_Realms_Sync_User_System_String_), [[2]](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/dotnet/latest/reference/Realms.Sync.PartitionSyncConfiguration.html#constructors)

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems you're mixing a lot of concepts here. Even though we use the partition key by default as the file name, the two are completely unrelated and you can always specify a custom file name and location. Changing the partition key field - e.g. going from `_partition` to `something_else` is an operation that you do on the server and doesn't affect the client at all, so not sure it's relevant.

Again, the filename doesn't hold any significance whatsoever, so you're free to choose whatever fits your needs.

Comment: And to clarify, both Andrea and I work at MongoDB on Realm, so we know what we're talking about. SO is not a great place to discuss/clarify things like that, but if you have doubts or want more information, feel free to post a question on the community forum (https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/c/atlas-app-services-realm/realm/58) and we can go over the precise architecture.

Comment: @Jay after I mentioned I work at MongoDB, do you really think I haven't built a sync project? If you rename your file and then do nothing, of course you're right - your app wouldn't look for the file under the new name. But if you update your sync configuration to point to the new file name, it will sync with it without any changes. I believe you're using the Swift SDK, so if you want to see it in action, set the `fileURL` of the configuration to something else and you'll see the Realm file created in the location you specified. It can be anything and doesn't need to contain the partition.

Comment: As I said, the answer is correct and doesn't attempt to show a fully featured application. If you want to use it, you'll need to devise a mechanism to store the location of the Realm file somewhere and update that value when you rename it.

Comment: @NikolaIrinchev I see. According to the Realm documentation [SyncConfiguration](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/SyncConfiguration.html) Objects do not have a `fileURL` parameter. I always hesitate using undocumented features; perhaps the documentation should be updated? Thanks for the clarification and insight on behind the scenes features. I have retracted my above comment based on the additional information.